# Install both Interbase and Firebird

Tags: firebird, interbase

Are there any conflicts if both Interbase and Firebird are installed on the same workstation?
Does anyone have any tips or best practices for this?

Answer (score 5):

Interbase uses port 3050 by default. So, you have to choose another number for Firebird server on the same machine. Port number is specified through firebird.conf file. You have to restart Firebird service after changing conf file.

Actually I have four different versions of FB running on my development computer. In this case every instance must use its own port number and have unique instance name given using -n switch of instsvc.

Dont forget to specify custom port number in a connection string. For port 3051 the string will look like:

Server/3051:path_to_db_file

A good link to [check](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/multiinstance.htm)

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying Firebird also uses 3050 by default? I think only recent versions of IB support running different versions on the same machine. The same for Firebird? And, is there any conflict with UDF implementation? Have you actually run FB and IB on the same machine?

Comment: I didn't try ib and fb on the same machine, but don't think there will be any problems. I didn't try fb versions prior to 2.0 but all recent work fine. As for UDF they are mere DLLs running in the process address space, so there will be no problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the port for either Firebird or InterBase, then it's OK.