# Connecting to local server via dBExpress

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, interbase

My D7 dBExpress project is supposed to connect to a local Interbase XE7 server.
It has the usual DBX setup: SqlConnection, SqlQuery, DataSetProvider and
ClientDataSet and does a simple 'select * from mytable'.

Last time I used it, it was working fine, but today when I ran it inside the IDE,
I get an exception as I call

```
ClientDataSet1.Open;
```

in my FormCreate (that call is the entire code of the project, btw).  The
exception is an EDatabaseError with msg "No mapping for Error Code Found." and happens in TSqlConnection.DoConnect

Comment: Have you tried connecting using IBConsole?  What does that say?

Comment: I have now.  IBConsole doesnt actually list my database,just "Local Server - gds_b".  When I click on that I get "Connection rejected by remote interface"

Comment: That sounds familiar - I got that error myself on time.  Turned out that something had sneaked Firebird onto my machine and it had hijacked the port IB usually listens on.  Take a look under Services to see whether there is an FB server running.  If there are, close it down (and start the IB server if not already running, of course).

Comment: You're right!  It was Firebird - except nothing sneeked it on, I installed it myself, not thinking it would affect Interbase.  Doh!  Thnks everso.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: As explained here for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/11119683/8041231

Comment: @Victoria: Controlling port usage etc in IB using the Windows drivers\etc\services file is explained in detail in section 4.4 on the IB XE7 Operations Guide, but that's not really the point, at least it wasn't for how the problem arose for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds familiar - I got that error myself one time, when I went back to an IB project after a few weeks.

It turned out that in the meantime something had sneaked Firebird onto my machine and it had hijacked the port IB usually listens on, and it was actually this FB server which was rejecting the connection, not the Interbase one!

Take a look under Services to see whether there is an FB server running. If there are, close it down (and start the IB server if not already running, of course).  Then try your DBX project again.

Somewhere in the IB docs, I found something which seemed to suggest there was a way of getting FB and IB servers to coexist, but to avoid falling into a similar trap another time, I wrote a couple of batch files to shut down one of them and start the other.  One is called "UseIB" and contains:

```
net stop "Firebird server - DefaultInstance"
net start "InterBase XE7 Server gds_db"
```

The other one, "UseFB" just does the opposite, of course.

Comment: An interesting decision. + 1 Also  you can change default port 3050 of Firebird(or Interbase) to something else. Then you can connect to Interbase or to Firebird just by changing the port in the connection string.